# In Android how to get preview frames while using media recorder

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2

How to catch camera preview frames during recording video via MediaRecorder in Android v4.0 and later without (or instead of) using FFmpeg libraries and MediaMuxer & MediaCodec API?